# Update B2C Custom Attribute String Collection via AD Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Can I define a [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) whose data type is `stringCollection` and update it via the Azure AD Graph API?  My experiment is failing:

> The request body contains unexpected characters/content for the specified content type and encoding

---

**Custom Attribute Definition**

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_array_test">
    <DisplayName>Array Test</DisplayName>
    <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Array Test in Token</UserHelpText>
</ClaimType>
```

---

**Using the [Graph API Sample client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)**

```
{
    "extension_[my-guid]_array_test": ["value 1", "value 2"]
}

Error Calling the Graph API:
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "The request body contains unexpected characters/content for the specified content type and encoding."
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second note in the documentation you provided states extension attributes currently only support the string data type.

As an alternative you could store your data as escaped JSON like this:

```
"extension_{GUID}_JsonAttribute": "{\"Item1\":\"Test\",\"Item2\":\"Data\"}"
```

Comment: Thanks nyoung.  That documentation is out of date, it also supports bool's and int's.  See this [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/3775).

Comment: B2C supports `stringCollections`, see [this code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/3b4898fec3bf0014b320beffa6eb52ad68eb6111/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L185).

Comment: B2C supports `stringCollections` for claims and standard AAD attributes (e.g. `otherMails`) but as you've pointed out the data types for extension attributes are string, bool and int so that is what you are currently limited to.

Comment: Note that you are currently limited to 256 characters when storing (JSON in) a string: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#extension-data-types--)