# Custom attribute as stringCollection on Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way (via api maybe?) to create a custom attribute as a stringCollection type on Azure AD B2C?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you could not do that, B2C just supports `stringCollection` for claims and standard AAD attributes (e.g. `otherMails`).

See this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418132/update-b2c-custom-attribute-string-collection-via-ad-graph-api)(Note the comments under the answer). If you want to improve it, you can vote the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31243018-support-stringcollection-type-for-user-custom-attr).